# Angular 7 .htaccess for sub domain

Tags: angular, .htaccess

For some reason the standard .htaccess is working on a standard www.domain.com url but for a subdomain app.domain.com no matter what .htaccess configuration I get a 404 when refreshing page.  Any ideas?
Current file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
</IfModule>
```

Apache Conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@gmail.com
    ServerName app.domain.com
    ServerAlias app.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app.domain.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/app.domain.com/html">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you give directory screen shot of your server? it will help to solve this quickly.

Comment: Added Apache Conf. hope this helps

Comment: Did you get it to work ?

Answer (score 2):

My htaccess file inside sub domain folder

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /subfolder-name/index.html
```

**index.html**

```
 <base href="/subfolder-name/">
```

hope this will help

Comment: it isn't a sub folder though. It is a sub domain that points to the root folder of the virtual host